# Можно ли с помощью XPath проверить, что в xml документе нет тега с нужным значением

Tags: xml, xpath

Можно ли как-то проверить с помощью XPath, что во всем xml документе нет элемента с конкретным значением, например:

```
<AnyText>
   123
<AnyText/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить задачу с применением функции `count() = 0`